# Why should I use <noscript>?

Tags: javascript, html, noscript

Humor me a bit here.

**Why would I use `<noscript>` in my pages?** The alternative (at least, the one I use) is the *Modernizr + no-js class* combo that is utilized with (for example) the HTML 5 Boilerplate, and this has been sufficient in all use cases so far.

The only reason I can think of of using `<noscript>` is to conditionally load resource files when JS is not enabled (most probably, CSS overrides?). I'm not sure if there a way to do that JS-free without using `<noscript>`, but even that use case seems that it can be worked around of.

### A lot of obvious answers below.

Yeah, `<noscript>` is used to conditionally show / hide HTML elements to the client when Javascript is not available. I know that. You know that. Everyone who works with HTML should most likely know that.

However, there are a lot of other ways to do the same thing, most of which are preferred over `<noscript>`. One is the `html.no-js` class that Modernizr switches, which I mentioned above.

So the idea behind the question is more of, is there anything that `<noscript>` can do for the web developer that is unique to it? That is, it's significant enough, but there's no other way to do it otherwise?

@Guffa below makes a good point with the advertisements.

Comment: So you can go `<noscript>alert('You MUST enable javascript!')</noscript>`

Comment: @Madmartigan ~ oh yessssssssss. I forgot about that! :D

Comment: Actually I thought it was for spamming key words: `<noscript>Best online deals free World of Warcraft Harry Potter XBOX Live eBay...</noscript>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, why should you? If you have no use for it, then just don't use it.

The `noscript` tag is often used for fallback in advertisments and visitor tracking. If the user has Javascript disabled, a plain image is loaded instead of running the script.

Comment: Nah, it's more of an *I-was-just-curious-and-I-want-to-cover-all-my-bases™* question.

Answer (score 4):

when the user's browser not support javascript or Javascript disabled.
the element which in  will show.

Answer (score 3):

If I recall correctly, one of the key use cases identified to justify its inclusion in HTML5 (as opposed to being classified as obsolete) was that it can be used with `<meta http-equiv="refresh" ...` inside of it so that if JS is unavailable the user gets automatically redirected to a non-JS version of the web site.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a page with crucial JS in it, use `noscript` to let your users know that their JS is disabled and they need to enable it to view the page.

Comment: You can actually witness this on Stack Overflow, there's a red warning banner.

Answer (score 0):

tag is use in case JavaScript of browser is disable. Content inside  is only display when your browser JavaScript is not enable.

You can use it for warning messages like: 'Hye your JavaScript is disable."

Comment: But you can do that with the Modernizr + no-js combo. Modernizr changes `html.no-js` to `html.js` (among others), so you can target that using CSS. i.e. `<div id="warning">Your JS is disabled.</div>` and `html.js #warning { display:none; }`.

Comment: It's not related to CSS or modernizer or any other JavaScript library. Suppose I have a web application dependent on JavaScript mostly. So in that case I can display a popup whenever user will open website and have JavaScript disable. say enable your JavaScript. User can't access your website till he/she not enable JavaScript.

Comment: Modernizer is not a inbuilt HTML API. We only include it when we need it. It's not necessary to include it in all projects. HTML allow you too use <noscript> even without using CSS, it's only display when your JavaScript is disable. Or in other words you can say that no-js is modernizer feature and <noscript> is HTML inbuilt feature. So it's not useless

Answer (score 0):

The best use case I can think of for noscript is when you are trying to use javascript to delay loading of assets for page performance. Consider a simple image lazy-loader:

```
<style>
    .no-js .lazy-load { display:none }
</style>
<img data-src="/path/to/img.jpg" src="/placeholder.png" class="lazy-load">
<noscript>
    <img src="/path/to/img.jpg">
</noscript>
<script>(function ($) {
    // http://stackoverflow.com/a/488073/1459873
    function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
        var $elem = $(elem);
        var $window = $(window);
        var docViewTop = $window.scrollTop();
        var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $window.height();
        var elemTop = $elem.offset().top;
        var elemBottom = elemTop + $elem.height();
        return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
    }
    function lazyLoad() {
        $('img.lazy-load').filter(function () {
            return isScrolledIntoView(this);
        }).each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.attr('src', $this.data('src'))
                 .removeClass('lazy-load')
                 .addClass('lazy-loaded');
        });
    }
    $.ready(lazyLoad);
    $(window).on('load scroll resize', lazyLoad);
}(jQuery))</script>
```

If you try to hide the lazy-loaded image with css classes, the no-js fallback will still load the image.